# Показ скрытого окна WPF с помощью комбинации клавиш

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, клавиатура, hotkeys

Необходимо, чтобы окно в приложении WPF было показано при нажатии определённой комбинации клавиш (например, CTRL + B). Окно заранее скрыто методом `Hide()`. Был испробован вариант с привязкой события KeyDown окну, но он не работает. Далее ошибочный код:

```
private void KeyBinding(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
  {
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B))
    {
      Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Implementing global hot keys in WPF](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/)?

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо, способ, описанный в статье, решил проблему.

Comment: ну и славно. Если есть желание, оформите ответом, что сделали.